permission needed in setting of grafana API
I am using grafana API to fetch settings.
GET /api/admin/settings
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer glsa_wFaOgY9XUHNCP3STz63hQNBwJelyvuIP_a3abc4d5

It responses this:
{
 "accessErrorId": "ACE0680604966",
 "message": "You'll need additional permissions to perform this action. Permissions needed: settings:read",
 "title": "Access denied"
}

How can I set additional permission?

From the Grafana Admin HTTP API documentation:

GET /api/admin/settings
Only works with Basic Authentication (username and password). See introduction for an explanation.

Try to use this API endpoint with basic authentication instead of an API key.
